# Connect MySQL Workbench with Django in Eclipse in a mac

Tags: python, mysql, django, eclipse, pydev

I am new to this so a silly question
I am trying to make a demo website using Django for that I need a database.. Have downloaded and installed MySQL Workbench for the same. But I don't know how to setup this.
Thank you in advance :)
I tried googling stuff but didn't find any exact solution for the same.
Please help

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you are asking. MySQL Workbench is a utility for administrating a database via a GUI, it's not a database and nor does it have anything to do with Eclipse or Django. There are plenty of instructions on how to set up MySQL itself for use with Django.

Comment: Can you please guide me with a few...

Comment: In django settings you have to set the database (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases). Just create a database, a user, and give it a password. Then put it in the right file in django. If you can run python manage.py migrate, it is connecting to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a mac user. I have luckily overcome the issue with connecting Django to mysql workbench. I assume that you have already installed Django package created your project directory e.g. mysite.

1. Initially after installation of MySQL workbench i have created a database : create database djo;
2. Go to mysite/settings.py and edit following piece of block.
   NOTE: Keep Engine name "django.db.backends.mysql" while using MySQL server. 
   and STOP the other Django MySQL service which might be running.

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'djo',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '****',       # Replace **** with your set password.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

3. now run manage.py to sync your database :
   $ python mysite/manage.py syncdb
   bash-3.2$ python manage.py syncdb
   Creating tables ...
   Creating table auth_permission
   Creating table auth_group_permissions
   Creating table auth_group
   Creating table auth_user_groups
   Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
   Creating table auth_user
   Creating table django_content_type
   Creating table django_session
   Creating table django_site

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (leave blank to use 'ambershe'): root
Email address: ambershe@netapp.com
/Users/ambershe/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.django/Data/app/python/lib/python2.7/getpass.py:83: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
  passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)

Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password: ****

Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Password (again): ****

Superuser created successfully.
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)